# Ember integration testing hangs after visiting route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

I am trying to do a simple integration test and I started from the integration example on the ember-cli website. Right now when I test in a browser (localhost:4200/tests), the follow case routes to where I expect, but then it just hangs and never does success or failure.

```
import Ember from "ember";
import { test } from 'ember-qunit';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';
var App;

module('Integration - Create Event', {
    setup: function() {
        App = startApp();
    },
    teardown: function() {
        Ember.run(App, App.destroy);
    }
});

test('check customers', function() {
    visit('/new');
    andThen(function() {
        fillIn('input#title', 'The Event Name');
        ok(true);
       // equal(find('.customers input[type="checkbox"]').length, 6, 'Customer checkboxes showing');

    });
});
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here? Or is there a different way to do it?

ember-cli 0.1.5 and ember 1.9.1

Edit:

```
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
```

Enabling logging shows that the transition completes, but andThen still never resolves or gets rejected.

Edit:

I think I've narrowed it down. I have a clock service that I am injecting into all controllers, but when I don't inject it at all, my test passes. I need the functionality the clock service provides, how can I still use it, but get my integration tests to work?

```
// services/clock.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
    pulse: Ember.computed.oneWay('_seconds').readOnly(),
    minutePulse: Ember.computed.oneWay('_minutes').readOnly(),
    tick: function () {
        var clock = this;
        Ember.run.later(function () {
            var seconds = clock.get('_seconds');
            var minutes = clock.get('_minutes');
            if (typeof seconds === 'number') {
                clock.set('_seconds', seconds + 1);
                if(Math.floor((seconds + 1) / 60) > minutes) {
                    clock.set('_minutes', minutes + 1);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }.observes('_seconds').on('init'),
    _seconds: 0,
    _minutes: 0
});
```

An example project can be found at https://github.com/RyanHirsch/ember-test-example. If I remove the run.later the tests will pass.

Comment: I was also having another issue with the URL on my tests and running `ember init` to compare to the default files showed that my config/environment.js had an incorrect value and should have been `ENV.locationType = 'none';`

Comment: I've also tried changing to `visit('/new').then(function() { ... }, function() { console.error('failed'); });` in hopes of catching a rejected promise, but the promise remains unfulfilled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to teddyz in the #emberjs channel on freenode for helping me with this problem. The issue is that the async helper `visit()` waits for the `Ember.run.later()` to finish, but the way I have this structured, before it finishes it triggers another `run.later`. So the visit basically waits forever. The solution seems to be to use setTimeout with an `Ember.run`. Code is below.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
    pulse: Ember.computed.oneWay('_seconds').readOnly(),
    minutePulse: Ember.computed.oneWay('_minutes').readOnly(),
    tick: function () {
        var clock = this;
        setTimeout(Ember.run.bind(clock, function () {
            var seconds = this.get('_seconds');
            var minutes = this.get('_minutes');
            if (typeof seconds === 'number') {
                this.set('_seconds', seconds + 1);
                if(Math.floor((seconds + 1) / 60) > minutes) {
                    this.set('_minutes', minutes + 1);
                }
            }
        }), clock.get('globalSettings.timeout'));
    }.observes('_seconds').on('init'),
    _seconds: 0,
    _minutes: 0
});
```

I've also created a `globalSettings` object per the discussion on the ember forums (http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/proper-way-to-handler-timers-w-ember-testing/4693/8) about the right way to handle timers and testing. This will allow for the adjusting of timeouts during testing (ie set them really low to test functionality and still maintain test execution speed)